# Passing current session/token of FirebaseAuth from Native Android App to a WebView's Firebase App

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, android-webview, firebase-security

**Scenario**

- It is a hybrid app (Most of Android **Native** Java and part html/**javascript** in a [WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview))
- **FirebaseAuth** for authentication/signIn [in Android Native app]
- **Firestore** as database
- Serverless app

**I want to**
pass the Authentication from Android Native app which was done via [FirebaseAuth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth)
TO
html/javascript screens which are being embedded as `Webview` in my app, so that i can call my Firebase DB without asking user to relogin.

**What I Tried**
i tried to signIn using [signInWithCustomToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithcustomtoken) and used the token generated from [getidtokenresult](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getidtokenresult) which throws error "INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN"

Any guidance will be helpful

Comment: Have you tried using the JWT token obtained with the [getIdToken()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getidtoken) function?

Comment: Yes it gives INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN

Comment: @Mi have you evered worked it out ? I am in the same situation. Thanks

Comment: @yvesb no i did not not get a good solution yet, only hack arounds that also stops working

Comment: If you are using Google Auth, you can use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69488147/473201

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Firebase Admin SDK in your Native app to generate a valid token for your client app to use with `signInWithCustomToken()`

Token Generation:

```
//The uid should uniquely identify the user or device you are authenticating
String uid = "some-uid";

String customToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(uid);
// Send token back to client
```

Use in client app:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

There is further information about this in the [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk)

Comment: The custom token should probably be generated server-side (as it requires special "service account" permissions), sent back to the native app, and then passed into the web view.